# Espresso "perform" gives error: "cannot be called on the main application thread"

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I am creating an instrumental espresso test that involves making an API call when a button is clicked and checking if the loader is visible. Afterwards, the activity is terminated using the following code:

```
val activityScenario: ActivityScenario<MainActivity> =
        ActivityScenario.launch(intent)

    activityScenario.onActivity { activity ->

        onView(withId(R.id.actionApproveContainer)).perform(click())
        onView(withText(R.string.loading)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
        onView(withText(R.string.loading)).check(doesNotExist())
        // Assert that the activity is finished
        assertTrue(activity.isFinishing)

    }
```

But when I am running test test case it gives *java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method cannot be called on the main application thread (on: main)* this error please suggest if i am doing something wrong here.